# Runs in compiler, declined online

Tags: c++

Problem Statement:

Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.

Input
Positive integer 0 < X <= 2000 - the amount of cash which Pooja wishes to withdraw. Non negative number 0<= Y <= 2000 with two digits of precision - Pooja's initial account balance.

Output
Output the account balance after the attempted transaction, given as a number with two digits of precision. If there is not enough money in the account to complete the transaction, output the current bank balance.

Example - Successful Transaction

Input: 30 120.00

Output: 89.50

Example - Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)

Input: 42 120.00

Output: 120.00

Example - Insufficient Funds

Input: 300 120.00

Output: 120.00

My partial solution (which seems to have a problem):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
int x;
float y;
cin>>x;
cin>>y;
if((x%5==0)&&(x<=(y+0.5)))
 cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<(y-(x+0.5));
else
 cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<y;
}
```

When i submit my answer, it says wrong submission but when i run it in my compiler, it runs just fine. where am i going wrong?

Comment: When you say you "submit your answer", can you clarify to what and how? We're being introduced to this problem blind. As you say, the code works as it should (right?), so the actual problem is the "submission" part which you've provided no details about.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't checked condition for input values.
In input condition it says x must be >0 and <2000 and y should in between 0 and 2000.
You've to check that values if they fall in given range.
Obviously negative number is not acceptable in transaction .
If condition is not satisfied then you should terminate your program from there only without showing any output. You can use return 0;
Add this to your code after taking input:

```
if(x <= 0 || x > 2000 || y <0 || y >2000)
    return 0;
```

Comment: You're doing another mistake here you're adding 0.5 to your balance variable that is "y" in if condition instead of that you've to subtract it from "y" and then check if it still has sufficient funds to complete task. Now this has to be the correct answer .